# Как поменять индексы элементов коллекции на случайные

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь создать колоду карт. Собираются элементы в коллекцию. Но ума не приложу как сделать порядок элементов случайным. Один из способов, которым хочу воспользоваться -  изменение индекса элемента на случайный. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Один из самых простых способов - это отсортировать по случайному числу, что думаю идеально подойдет для колоды карт так как элементов в коллекции будет мало:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
  internal static class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      var rand = new Random();
      var ss = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

      var randomizedCollection = ss.OrderBy(x => rand.Next());

      foreach (var i in randomizedCollection)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Более хитрые и оптимизированные способы - пожалуйста [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)

Comment: Сортировка по нестабильному ключу имеет право упасть.

Comment: @VladD, имеется в виду в моем примере или глобально?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, глобально. `OrderBy` вполне имеет право опросить ключ несколько раз (и исходить из того, что он не поменяется).